# Почему информация о пользователе сохраняется только при повторной отправке формы?

Tags: php, wordpress, form

Есть сайт на `wordpress` и форма регистрации, в которой (обязательное поле) логин пользователя хочу получать по фамилии не выводя это поле на экране. Для этого в его **value** помещаю значение выводимое в поле фамилия, но такой вариант срабатывает только при повторном нажатии на кнопку **submit** (в первый раз выскакивает ошибка, которая ругается на незаполненное обязательное поле логина). Как этот момент исправить?

```
<form name="registerform" class="registerform" id="registerform<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" action="<?php $template->the_action_url( 'register' ); ?>" method="post">
<p><label for="last_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">Фамилия:<span class="necessarily">*</span></label><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="regular-text" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'last_name' ); ?>"  /></p>
<p class="submit">
          <input type="hidden" name="user_login" id="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'last_name' ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'theme-my-login' ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php $template->the_redirect_url( 'register' ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="instance" value="<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />
        </p>
</form>
```

Comment: @Вася за что минус-то?

Comment: Предположительно, кто то недолюбливает wp))

Comment: @borodatych это не повод минусовать все подряд.

Comment: Я сейчас скостил))) Но это был не я, зуб даю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте посмотреть на html-исходник формы. В первый раз post-значения не указаны. Что же ж вы хотели-то получить, если загоняете пустое значение на сервере?

Возможное решение в лоб, находится в районе скриптинга:

```
<p><label for="IDLastName">Фамилия:</label>
   <input type="text" name="last_name" id="IDLastName" value=""  />
</p>
<input type="text" name="user_login" id="IDUserLogin" value="" />
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#IDLastName').keyup(function() {
        $('#IDUserLogin').val($('#IDLastName').val());
    })
});
</script>
```